# No errors are showing - iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

Everytime there is an error in my application, my iPhone simulator just closes. I'm programming in the most recent version of XCode and I'm on Debug configuration. Why is it that anytime there is a problem, my application just closes in the simulator and doesn't display any error message? This has been going on for a while now.

Also, why does the following occur?

1. I press command-b (to build the application)
2. It shows I have some warnings
3. I press command-b again and the warnings go away

I'd like all warnings to stay up so that I can fix them...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're not running in the debugger.  There are two options, "Build and Run" and "Build and Debug".  When you have a crash during "Run" mode, the iPhone (or simulator) will just close your app. You should still be able to get a sense of what happened by looking at the console window. In "Debug" mode, XCode halts your app at the point of the crash and you can inspect it a bit in the debugger.

"Debug" and "Release" configurations are only peripherally related to this issue, and determine how the compiler does its work in putting together the executable and bundle.

Build warnings disappear because you are using precompiled files.  XCode only recompiles the files that have changed.  You can recompile all files by selecting "Clean" from the build menu and then building again.